# Is an antlr4 parse tree thread safe?

Tags: antlr4

I would like to know if the parse tree generated by antlr 4 is thread safe.  There is nothing in the documentation that indicates that it is or is not.  I want to cache generated parse trees so that I do not have to reparse them for the same input, but I want to make sure that it is safe before I do so.

Comment: Did you find out if it is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to make them thread safe. It's a data structure you have to protect like any other.

Comment: Assuming my visitor does not alter the tree data, can I assume that it is thread safe?  Does the act of visiting a parse tree cause modification to the parse tree within the internals of the antlr target runtime?  I am pretty sure that it does not alter data internally, but I was hoping to get a definitive answer from one of the developers.

Comment: Read only access from multiple threads has never been a problem. It's always an issue when one or more threads modify something.